# Is this circular reasoning?

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

My course problem booklet (Mathematics BSc, second year module in analysis, unpublished) has:

> Let $a \geq b \geq 0$. We define sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ by taking $a_1$ and $b_1$ to be $a$ and $b$ respectively, and requiring that for $n \geq 1$,
> $$
> a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(a_n+b_n) \hspace{1em} \text{and} \hspace{1em} b_{n+1} = \sqrt{a_nb_n}.
> $$
> In other words, $a_{n+1}$ is the arithmetic mean of $a_n$ and $b_n$ while $b_{n+1}$ is their geometric mean.

> Prove that $b_n \leq b_{n+1} \leq a_{n+1} \leq a_n$.

For the left inequality, the solution booklet has:

> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> b_{n+1}^2 - b_n^2
> & = a_nb_n - a_{n-1}b_{n-1} \\
> & = \frac{1}{2}(a_{n-1}+b_{n-1})\sqrt{a_{n-1}b_{n-1}} - a_{n-1}b_{n-1} \\
> & = \sqrt{a_{n-1}b_{n-1}}\left(\frac{1}{2}(a_{n-1}+b_{n-1})-\sqrt{a_{n-1}b_{n-1}}\right) \geq 0
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> by the theorem of the means. So $b_{n+1}^2 \geq b_n^2$ and taking square roots we have $b_{n+1} \geq b_n$ for all $n$.

Now, I see that the Theorem of the Means (ToM) gives us that
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \; \frac{1}{2}(a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}) \geq \sqrt{a_{n-1}b_{n-1}} \\
\therefore & \; \frac{1}{2}(a_{n-1}+b_{n-1})-\sqrt{a_{n-1}b_{n-1}} \geq 0
\end{aligned}
$$
but we want
$$
\sqrt{a_{n-1}b_{n-1}}\left(\frac{1}{2}(a_{n-1}+b_{n-1})-\sqrt{a_{n-1}b_{n-1}}\right) \geq 0
$$
and that also requires
$$
\sqrt{a_{n-1}b_{n-1}} \geq 0.
$$
Unless we reason
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \; \text{this is real analysis} \\
\therefore & \; \sqrt{a_{n-1}b_{n-1}} \in \mathbb{R} \\
\therefore &  \; a_{n-1}b_{n-1} \geq 0 \\
\therefore & \; \sqrt{a_{n-1}b_{n-1}} \geq 0,
\end{aligned}
$$
this would seem to require
$$
a_{n-1},b_{n-1} \leq 0 \hspace{1em} \text{or} \hspace{1em} a_{n-1},b_{n-1} \geq 0
$$
and to get the expected $a_{n-1},b_{n-1} \geq 0$ from the given $a \geq b \geq 0$ would seem to require us to assume the inequalities we're trying to prove.

Thoughts?

Comment: $a_1 = a > 0$ and  $b_1 = b > 0$ . From this and the definitions of $b_{n+1} = (a_n b_n)^{1/2} $ and $a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2} (a_n + b_n)$ we get inductive proofs that $a_n > 0$ and $b_n > 0$

Comment: @user3257842 Right. I'm sure I could have spotted that if I were fresher. Thanks.